# Google Tag Manager - firing events from rest api

Tags: google-tag-manager

Some of my events are getting fired from frontend for both google analytics and facebook pixel and they are getting captured properly through GTM.

but now i have a functionality which is getting done from cron and is served   from backend. I need to capture a event in both google analytics and facebook pixel when this is getting captured.

We need to fire the https (rest based) calls for capturing this.

Kindly help on this how this can be achieved.

Comment: I am thinking about the logic of such an endeavour. Is the information someone connected to the user visit you need to send the event with? Can it be processed in back end and displayed during user visit and send with event tag? Also I would not recommend to use GA or FB pixel as kind of business data storage. Otherwise if you still need to send this information for GA you use Measurement Protocol to connect eg. CRM ids, orders for signed in users etc. For FB check their documentation, never did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: While this was correct at the time of writing, Google has since introduced s[erver-side tagging via GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside), which conceivably can be used for server-to-server communication.

--

GTM has no serverside API to trigger tracking calls (the GTM API is for managing tags that will be wrapped into a Javascript function. There is no tracking backend to do calls against).

You need to send your calls directly to [GA via the measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/)  or respectively to [Facebook via offline conversions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions/v2.9).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
create an event listener on button click to connect to the API to collect the data

then with an event push the data you want to a Datalayer

and then use it as you wish.