# PHP cronjob which generates GTM script

Tags: php, cron, google-tag-manager

I am having problems with my session library that's why sometimes I am losing data on my thank-you page. As a result of this, I can't send data to GTM (dataLayer.push) on thank-you page because of missing data.

To avoid missing data on GTM, I decided to write a cronjob which will detect the missing ones from database and send them to GTM programmatically each 15 minutes.

After investigating, I found this : 
https://github.com/antoniotajuelo/google-tag-manager-php
a library to send data to GTM. It is generating/outputting GTM container, scripts, push object, etc...

I wrote the method by using that library, It is working well when I call it on browser like "https://example.com/my-method". When I check source code of page, I see that It is rendering Google Tag Manager container, datalayer, scripts, push, etc...

After all, I added it as a cron on server level: 

*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -k 'https://example.com/my-method' >/dev/null 2>&1

I thought It will work well but It is not. Js is only working on browser side, not on server side. Is there a way to make it work on server level (rendered scripts, etc...)?

Comment: Why not just fix the session issue?

Comment: It is an old website using codeigniter framework and we spent 2 months to detect session issues but no chance. Nevermind, somehow we have to send data to GTM programmatically and the solution above exploded because of not working js on server side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Tag Manager - firing events from rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852843/google-tag-manager-firing-events-from-rest-api)

Comment: GTM does not have a serverside API. The linked library creates the client side code, it does not send data to GTM. However if your problem is with analytics you can send data via the measurement protocol.

Comment: Thanks @Eike, but as I can see, measurement protocol is not enough to send my all datalayer push items.
https://imgur.com/2b2V6eU